# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, Nvidia drivers stop working after a couple of reboots. Intel or AMD

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia

This has been happening for over a year.

I have two systems, both running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. One system is Intel I7 and the other is Ryzen 5. One card is GTX1060 and the other is RTX2060. The only point of similarity that I can think of is the version of Ubuntu 18.04.

I have never upgraded.

After a couple of reboots the drivers seem to fail. I have blacklisted nouveau in both systems ages ago. No matter which driver I download either 470 or 450, etc, the same thing happens.

The system could be working for months but after a couple of reboots, the drivers will fail and I will have to do a reinstall.

Is there a way to avoid this?

Thank You
Tom

Comment: Are you by any chance installing the binaries from Nvidia (instead of installing the same drivers from the Ubuntu repository)? If so, there's your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried open a terminal and type the command `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`?

I had Ubuntu 18.04 some time ago with a GTX 1050Ti working after I used this command.

Don't forget to purge all the nvidia drivers you've installed before doing that.

Comment: Actually, that did work! Not sure why it happens in the first place, but it is an easier fix than the one that I had.  Thank You.

Comment: Glad to help 